# How to include "CHECK" constraint to backup done via phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, phpmyadmin, check-constraints

When I export my database from phpMyAdmin (quick method), it does not include `CHECK` constraints. However, when I run `SHOW CREATE TABLE table`, I see the constraints. Moreover, foreign constraints are backed up.

In addition, when I take the backup using mysqldump, `CHECK` constraints are included in the file.

**Is there any way to tell phpMyAdmin to include the `CHECK` constraints in the backup?**

I have checked the "custom" method, but I do not see any option.

Comment: Hmmm...  I wonder what else is missing from the "quick method".

Comment: Please check does your phpMyAdmin version is fresh enough? Old MySQL versions does not implement CHECK constraints (parses but ignores), and old phpMyAdmin version may simply ignore them while backing up.

Comment: Hi @Akina, phpMyAdmin version is the latest one (5.2.0)